# Is it possible to use CSS to give an arbitrary (non-media) element an intrinsic ratio?

Tags: css, responsive-design

If I have an image or another media type (`img`, `video`, `object`, `svg`), then the browser 'knows' that it is 'supposed' to have a certain height and width ratio. This is useful for responsive design, because then you can set e.g. `width: 100%; height: auto;` and the height will scale to maintain the correct aspect ratio.

How (if at all) can CSS be used to give, say, an arbitrary `div` an intrinsic ratio?

Put another way, can an arbitrary element be given a height that always resolves to a certain constant times its width (or vice-versa), when the exact dimensions can't be known ahead of time, and computed dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) or if you need better browser support you can use [`padding-bottom`](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) with a percentage.

So essentially:

```css
.cool-div {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}
```